# Apex double override

Tags: apex, inheritance

I have the following classes:

```
public virtual class BaseWorker {
    public virtual myMethod(){
    }
}

public virtual class SonWorker extends BaseWorker{
    public virtual override myMethod(){
    }
}

public class GrandSonWorker extends SonWorker{
    public override myMethod(){
    }
}
```

Furthermore I have a `WorkerManager` class that works with `BaseWorker` instances. calling the myMethod.

The problem is that I'm not sure if this syntax is correct. It compiles, but it doesn't work as expected since the `GrandsonWorker`'s method is never executed, but the `SonWorker`'s method instead.

Any ideas?

Comment: How do you make instances of `BaseWorker` when the class is abstract?

Comment: @martin my bad, it isn't abstract, it's virtual! :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This test demonstrates that "double override" works as [expected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_overriding):

```
@IsTest
private class OverrideTest {

    public virtual class BaseWorker {
        public virtual String myMethod(){
            return 'base';
        }
    }

    public virtual class SonWorker extends BaseWorker{
        public virtual override String myMethod(){
            return 'son';
        }
    }

    public class GrandSonWorker extends SonWorker{
        public override String myMethod(){
            return 'grand';
        }
    }

    @IsTest
    static void test1() {
        System.assertEquals('base', new BaseWorker().myMethod());
        System.assertEquals('son', new SonWorker().myMethod());
        System.assertEquals('grand', new GrandSonWorker().myMethod());
    }

    @IsTest
    static void test2() {
        BaseWorker w = new GrandSonWorker();
        System.assertEquals('grand', w.myMethod());
    }
}
```

`test2` demonstrates that it is the type of the object *instance* (`GrandSonWorker`) that determines the method invoked not the type of the object *reference* (`BaseWorker`) - [dynamic dispatching](https://lukasatkinson.de/2016/dynamic-vs-static-dispatch/).

Comment: True... I guess it's a problem with the trigger framework I'm using and not the inheritance itself then. I'll keep in mind the idea of testing things this way tho, I hadn't thought of it! :)

Comment: @JavierGarcíaManzano Yeah its easy to draw wrong conclusions when dealing with complicated code so using anonymous Apex or a throw away unit test to double check can help.